# Update document if only present otherwise do not insert document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I don't want to insert a new document in MongoDB if no matching data found.

findOneAndUpdate() doesn't seem to be working. It throws a run time error saying "Cannot read property 'firstField' of null"

My schema looked like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const TestSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstField: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      sparse: true
    },
    secondField: {
      type: [String],
      required: true
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Test", TestSchema);
```

My query looked like this:

```
Test.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    secondField: { $in: req.body.second }
  },
  { $set: { firstField: req.body.first } },
  { new: true },
  (err, test) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("There are no matching first fields");
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("Field updated successfully");
});
```

Comment: Any help in identifying the right way helps a lot. Thanks !!!

Comment: Please post the sample document and the code for how you have tried to save it, in your question. (You can use the `edit` link/button at the bottom of your post to edit).

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter and update and then with UpdateOne. For eg.

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Collection name");

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("the field you want to filter by","the value of the field");
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("the field you want to update","value")
collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```